# Duality in Langrange Multiplier

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

The problem is to minimize $$f(x) = x^T.x$$

subject to condition $$Ax = b$$

With the help of **Lagrange Multipliers**, which gives the equation $$L(x,\lambda) = x^Tx + {\lambda}^T(Ax-b)$$

The solution here would be $${\delta}_x L(x,\lambda) = 0$$

Which gives the $x$ value that minimizes $f(x)$. Thus $$ 2x+A^T\lambda = 0$$ $$=> x = -\frac 12A^T\lambda$$

What am not able to figure out is the following:

1. the significance of the $\lambda$ value obtained by differentiating the langrange, which means $${\delta}_{\lambda} L(x,\lambda) = 0$$ $$ => Ax - b = 0$$ and subsituting x , we get $$\lambda = -2({A{A^T}})^{-1}b$$
2. What is the dual problem here?

Please kindly help me.

Comment: The dual problem is $\sup_\lambda \inf_x L(x,y)$. Here, $\inf_x L(x,y) = -\frac14 \lambda^T AA^T \lambda - \lambda^T b$.

Comment: so, from the above equation, we get the maximizer and its same as the one stated in the question right? $\lambda = -2({A{A^T}})^{-1}b$

Comment: sure. Notice that $L(x,y)$ is differentiable and convex in $x$. Thus $\partial_x L(x,y) = 0$ is sufficient for $x$ to be a minimum.

Comment: ok. am slightly confused here. please bare with me. To minimize $f(x)$. I formed the lagrange, which gives $x = -\frac 12A^T\lambda$. Now, which function is to be maximized in the dual problem?

Comment: or is $x = -\frac 12A^T\lambda$ the minimizes the lagrange equation?

Comment: $x = -\frac12 A^T \lambda$ is the minimizer of $L(\cdot, y)$ for a fixed $y$.

Comment: okay. So the X that minimizes $f(x)$ would be $x = (A^T)({A{A^T}})^{-1}b$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29814/discussion-between-lakshmi-narayanan-and-user251257).

Comment: $x = -\frac12 A^T \lambda$ then transpose of x i.e $x^T = (-\frac12 A^T \lambda)^T = + \frac12 \lambda^T A$ or $- \frac12 \lambda^T$? would you explain which one is correct?